# What are Ford Prefect and Zaphod Beeblebrox singing in their death hymn?

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy, music-identification

In the the original series from the 80's at the end they are singing a betelguzian death hymn. In the [german version of episode 4](https://youtu.be/B4NXrlTw5Fw) it is a bit better understandable. It seems like they are singing something like:

```
saklamoa astragad otrimantium brambriar
```

Comment: I don't think you'll get an answer, unless you happen to find someone who speaks Betelgeusian.

Comment: It seems to me that what you need to be looking for is the script for that episode.

Comment: Is your Babel Fish not working?

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking for a word-for-word translation, I suspect you'll be out of luck unless you can actually find someone who [speaks Betelgeusian](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%22betelgeusian%20translation%20services%22) (zero results found)

As far as the meaning of the song's, and possibly the song's lyrics, this is actually explained in the episode.

> **Arthur:** *What the hell are you doing?*
>
> **Ford:** *This is an ancient Betelgeuse Death Anthem. **It means "After this, things can only get better".***

Comment: Considering that Betelgeusian is a language in which "Ix," translates to "boy who is not able satisfactorily to explain what a Hrung is, nor why it should choose to collapse on Betelgeuse Seven", a word-for-word translation might be too long for stackexchange anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I found this fan-transcript for episode 4 [here](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy&episode=s01e04) which seems to fit quite good:

> Well it's really been nice running into you again, Zaphod.
>   Zaglabor astragard # Hootrimansion Bambriar
>   What the hell are you doing?! - A Betelgeuse death anthem. It means, "After this, things
>   can only get better. "
>   Zaglabor astragard! # Hootrimansion Bambriar

In the german version it is slightly different:

> Saklamoar astragard! # Otrimantion Brambriar
>   (with german pronountiation)

Comment: The LP version has different "lyrics" again.  It was something like "Zaglabooor zril droolty gastro...gangrene grog bantry fox..."